# MS Access: How to display list from one or two fields as span of columns?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016, ms-access-forms, ms-access-reports

Work has me creating an Access 2016 database (haven't used Access in years) for coworkers to record what program slots they are using on CNC machines. My tables have the following field names (plus a few more):

```
id (PK), programNum, programName, inUse
```

The database has thousands of records and I'm trying to display just the program numbers like a spreadsheet (instead of a single-column list):

```
1001  |  1101  |  1201  |  ...  |  9901
1002  |  1102  |  1202      .        .
1003  |  1103  |  1203      .        .
1004  |  1104  |  1204      .        .
  .        .        .       .        .
  .        .        .       .        .
  .        .        .       .        .
1100  |  1200  |  1300  |  ...  |  9999
```

Additionally, I want to use the "inUse" values (Yes/No) to determine the color of each number (to show if it's available or not).

Essentially, I want to display 50 or 100 items in one column, then move to the next column and repeat until the end of the list of programs (not the same for each table)

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible with MS Access (without heavy VBA scripting)? If so, any ideas on how to go about it? I'm hoping to use this on a form (for selection), or a report (for display only).

Thanks in advance!

P.S. The query portion is straightforward (select programNum, inUse from tableName), but I'm hung up on how to create a form or report to display the info in this way.

Comment: You can do this in a **report** with columns, but not in a form.

Comment: Yes, indeed it can be done in a report but not in a form, so the value you are displaying won't be editable.

Comment: It can be done, but not without some complex SQL. You can create a crosstab query, with `FieldName Mod 100` as row heading, and `Abs(FieldName/100)` as column heading, and `Max(FieldName)` as value. That should get you started.

Comment: Ok. How do I do it with a report? Also, can I color the numbers on the report, based on the "inUse" value for each program number?

I can make do without using it on a form... editing would've been easier, but isn't a deal breaker.

Comment: Use Conditional Formatting for the conditional display of color. Report with Column settings (snaking down then right) might get what you want. Forcing a column break on multiples of 100 will be the real trick.

Comment: If your setup is back end linked to front end and each user can have their own front end, you can use VBA to dynamically generate and populate a series of single column list boxes next to each other so that they look like one multi-column list box. The VBA to do it not actually that complicated but the design on runtime aspect of this solution requires exclusive rights to the database file.

Comment: I have used technique of listboxes on report to provide the columnar effect to display 7 days of data and each column would have different number of records. Controlling the column break was too complicated. Listbox won't grow/shrink so it has to be sized to fit the most number of possible records. I can't see this technique will be necessary for the example data.

Comment: Oh, and no VBA involved with my listbox emulating columns report and exclusive rights not required.

Comment: And I just figured out a CROSSTAB query to do the same thing as the listboxes.